# Unable to create Object Storage in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack, credentials, object-storage

Whenever I try to create an Object Storage in IBM Bluemix using free plan, the Services is created but when accessed, I get this error

Unable to acquire openstack credentials. I tried deleting and creating services many times and using different browsers without luck

any suggestions?

thanks

error:

[image: error]

Comment: The message asks to contact Bluemix support. Did you?

Comment: I did and never heard from them!!

Comment: @Zak Hashash - Can you tell us when you raised the ticket? Do you have the ticket #? We have someone searching for it.